# Making changes to postgres databse on heroku - django app

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

Hey Im using heroku for the first time and I made some changes to some models in Django.

This is what I do:

```
heroku pg:info --app podiium-staging
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.1.11
Created:     2012-10-20 00:57 UTC
Data Size:   9.1 MB
Tables:      61
Rows:        48/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

Then:

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL --app=podiium-staging
---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL
psql (9.3.3, server 9.1.11)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

podiium-staging::TEAL=> alter table debate_debate add column debate_image text;
```

Ok So I thaught I had altered the database, but in django that column does not exist.

So I guess Im making changes to another DB?

Please help me, I am so confused with this sh%T

Answer (score 0):

What are your database settings in settings.py?

Also, have you considered using South for schema changes? It makes it much easier.

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html